# Azure Administration screen wordpress

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

Initially while creating website in azure i opted for Wordpress option and successfully done the job. 
After doing few changes of alignment and removing unnecessary things i log out from word press from my site.
But now i m not getting any way for login in back to my Administration Screen of Wordpress over my site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like more of a WordPress issue than an Azure issue. In any case: try visiting yoursite.azurewebsites.net/wp-login.php.